# Can I feed lower than rated voltage?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, components

I'm poking around on eBay for some capacitors to use in circuits which I'm working on and see that they have a rated voltage.

After some quick research, I [**found**](http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-132218.html) that going **over** the rated voltage of a component can cause harm and/or destroy it.

Does the same happen if I go **under** it?

My circuit runs on a 1.5V battery and the cheap (xD) capacitors I was looking at have a rating of 50V and 16V. Will this affect my circuit in anyway, as I am running like 58.5V less through them?

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to purchase electrolytic capacitors from untrusted sellers. Quality matters with electrolytic capacitors, and it varies wildly. Most Japanese caps are good and most Chinese caps are bad. Note that there are also counterfeits.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Oh of course! Japanese stuff is like.. godly. I only did the cheap search to see what my worst options were, but scrolling down (getting more expensive) they all still contained a rated voltage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the component what a rating means. Some voltage ratings are such that you should supply the device only the rated voltage (+/- some tolerance). Examples of these are most IC's/complete devices, which won't work properly when given too little voltage, and can be damaged if given too much voltage (not to say that too low voltage can't damage the device, or too high a voltage will allow a device to work properly).

Others are a simple max bound. Any voltage below the rated voltage is fine. This is the category capacitors fall into. The higher the limit, the better. So both the 50V and 16V capacitors will work just fine with a 1.5V battery. However, only the 50V capacitor will still work if you decide to hook up a 24V battery.

Comment: So, these will work with a 1.5V battery? http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/50-16V-100UF-Electrolytic-Capacitor-5X12mm-85-/191452887893?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item2c937b3b55

Comment: They should be fine. Be careful because those are polarized capacitors; they only work correctly when the positive terminal has a higher voltage. Applying a negative voltage (i.e. flipping the capacitor around) can cause them to fail catastrophically.

Comment: Not only do electrolytics

Comment: @helloworld922 Yes, I know about polarization. Like LED's. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You understand that when the equipment is off, there's no voltage at all on the capacitors. Clearly, there's no minimum voltage requirement (unlike batteries), at least with regard to harm/safety.

However, with some capacitor technologies, there's a strong dependency of the value of the capacitance on the instantaneous voltage. If you need super-accurate capacitance values in your application, you'll need to pay attention to what the datasheets say about this.